# Saints Who Disobeyed Parents or Superiors in Order to Avoid Committing Sin

Tags: catholicism, sin, saint, thomas-aquinas, obedience

Regarding Catholic Saints who were members of the laity---I would like to know if there are any who disobeyed their parents in order not to commit sin. (I exclude superiors here, for one could name perhaps all or most of the martyrs.)

Regarding Catholic Saints who were religious---were there any who disobeyed either their immediate superiors or parents in order to avoid sin? (I know, for instance, that St. Thomas Aquinas' family was against him  joining the Dominican order and hired a prostitute in order to tempt him---but I don't know if either parent was involved.)

Comment: If this is related to the commandment to "*honour thy father and thy monther*", keep in mind that the original Hebrew word, [H3513 - kāḇaḏ - Strong's Hebrew Lexicon (kjv)](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h3513/kjv/wlc/0-1/#:~:text=to%20make%20honourable,glorify), means "*to make honourable*" or "*to glorify*"; it doesn't mean to obey.

Comment: Known of several examples but cannot recall them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Saints Who Disobeyed Parents or Superiors in Order to Avoid Committing Sin?**

[**St. Thomas Aquinas**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Aquinas) disobeyed his parents when he felt called to become a Dominican. He was imprisoned by his parents with the help of Thomas’ brothers. Some biographies state that his mother sent prostitutes to him while in prison in order to brake his resolve.

> At the age of nineteen, Thomas resolved to join this Dominican Order. Thomas's change of heart, however, did not please his family. In an attempt to prevent Theodora's interference in Thomas's choice, the Dominicans arranged to move Thomas to Rome, and from Rome, to Paris. However, while on his journey to Rome, per Theodora's instructions, his brothers seized him as he was drinking from a spring and took him back to his parents at the castle of Monte San Giovanni Campano.
>
> Thomas was held prisoner for almost one year in the family castles at Monte San Giovanni and Roccasecca in an attempt to prevent him from assuming the Dominican habit and to push him into renouncing his new aspiration. Political concerns prevented the Pope from ordering Thomas's release, which had the effect of extending Thomas's detention. Thomas passed this time of trial tutoring his sisters and communicating with members of the Dominican Order.
>
> Family members became desperate to dissuade Thomas, who remained determined to join the Dominicans. At one point, two of his brothers resorted to the measure of hiring a prostitute to seduce him. As included in the official records for his canonization, Thomas drove her away wielding a burning log—with which he inscribed a cross onto the wall—and fell into a mystical ecstasy; two angels appeared to him as he slept and said, "Behold, we gird thee by the command of God with the girdle of chastity, which henceforth will never be imperiled. What human strength can not obtain, is now bestowed upon thee as a celestial gift." From then onwards, Thomas was given the grace of perfect chastity by Christ, a girdle he wore till the end of his life. The girdle was given to the ancient monastery of Vercelli in Piedmont, and is now at Chieri, near Turin.

[**St. John of the Cross**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_of_the_Cross) disobeyed his superiors when the Carmelite reform was being started. Carmelites were living a life non-conforming to the spirit of religion and John of the Cross knew it.

> On the night of 2 December 1577, a group of Carmelites opposed to reform broke into John's dwelling in Ávila and took him prisoner. John had received an order from superiors, opposed to reform, to leave Ávila and return to his original house. John had refused on the basis that his reform work had been approved by the papal nuncio to Spain, a higher authority than these superiors. The Carmelites therefore took John captive. John was taken from Ávila to the Carmelite monastery in Toledo, at that time the order's leading monastery in Castile, with a community of 40 friars.
>
> John was brought before a court of friars, accused of disobeying the ordinances of Piacenza. Despite his argument that he had not disobeyed the ordinances, he was sentenced to a term of imprisonment. He was jailed in a monastery where he was kept under a brutal regime that included public lashings before the community at least weekly, and severe isolation in a tiny stifling cell measuring barely 10 feet by 6 feet. Except when rarely permitted an oil lamp, he had to stand on a bench to read his breviary by the light through the hole into the adjoining room. He had no change of clothing and a penitential diet of water, bread and scraps of salt fish.[28] During his imprisonment, he composed a great part of his most famous poem Spiritual Canticle, as well as a few shorter poems. The paper was passed to him by the friar who guarded his cell. He managed to escape eight months later, on 15 August 1578, through a small window in a room adjoining his cell. (He had managed to pry open the hinges of the cell door earlier that day.)
>
> After being nursed back to health, first by Teresa's nuns in Toledo, and then during six weeks at the Hospital of Santa Cruz, John continued with the reforms. In October 1578 he joined a meeting at Almodóvar del Campo of reform supporters, better known as the Discalced Carmelites. There, in part as a result of the opposition faced from other Carmelites, they decided to request from the Pope their formal separation from the rest of the Carmelite order.

[**St. Mariam Baouardy**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariam_Baouardy#Early_life) disobeyed her uncle (legal guardian) when it came to an arranged marriage. Her throat was cut, but was miraculously healed.

> When Baouardy was eight, her uncle and his wife moved to Alexandria, Egypt to improve their situation. Five years later, in 1858, when she was aged 13, in keeping with tradition, she was engaged by her uncle to his wife's brother, who lived in Cairo. The night before the wedding, she had a religious experience in which she felt called not to marry but to offer her life to God. Upon being told this the following morning, her uncle flew into a rage and beat her severely. Despite this and the subsequent ill-treatment she began to experience from her uncle, she stayed firm in her decision.
>
> Nonetheless, Baouardy felt depressed and alone. She wrote her brother, then living in Nazareth, asking him to visit her. The young male servant she asked to deliver the letter drew out of her the cause for her sadness. Upon learning of this, he attempted to woo her for himself, inviting her to convert to Islam. She rejected his proposal, which caused the young man to fly into a rage, in which he drew a knife and cut her throat. He then dumped her body in a nearby alley.
>
> Baouardy then experienced what she was convinced was a miracle. As she related later, a "nun dressed in blue" brought her to a grotto which she could never identify, stitched her wounds, and took care of her. Her voice was affected for the rest of her life as a result of the cut, which a French doctor later measured as being 10 cm. (nearly 4 inches) wide. After being cared for by this mysterious figure for a month, she recovered enough to leave and find work as a domestic servant in the home of an Arab Christian family in the city.

As a side note St. George of Lydda is the [Patron Saint of Civil Disobedience](https://kuyperian.com/george-of-lydda-patron-saint-of-civil-disobedience/#prettyPhoto/0/).

Answer (score 2):

Consider St. Dymphna:

https://franciscanmissionassoc.org/prayer-requests/devotional-saints/st-dymphna/the-story-of-st-dymphna/

A beautiful princess whose beauty closely resembled that of her deceased mother. After her father's men were unsuccessful in finding another woman whose looks were comparable to that of the wife he had lost---the idea was planted in his head to marry his daughter Dymphna. When this was proposed to her, she fled. Ultimately, her father caught up with her, and after her subsequent refusals of his propositions, he beheaded her himself.

She is now the patron saint of mental illness.

Answer (score 1):

[St. Perpetua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetua_and_Felicity), who was martyred in the early 3rd century, refused to renounce Christianity despite the urging of her father. In her own words:

> A few days after, the report went abroad that we were to be tried. Also my father returned from the city spent with weariness; and he came up to me to cast down my faith saying: Have pity, daughter, on my grey hairs; have pity on your father, if I am worthy to be, called father by you; if with these hands I have brought you unto this flower of youth- and I have preferred you before all your brothers; give me not over to the reproach of men. Look upon your brothers; look upon your mother and mother's sister; look upon your son, who will not endure to live after you. Give up your resolution; do not destroy us all together; for none of us will speak openly against men again if you suffer aught.
>
> This he said fatherly in his love, kissing my hands and grovelling at my feet; and with tears he named me, not daughter, but lady. And I was grieved for my father's case because he would not rejoice at my passion out of all my kin; and I comforted him, saying: That shall be done at this tribunal, whatsoever God shall please; for know that we are not established in our own power, but in God's. And he went from me very sorrowful.
>
> ...
>
> We went up to the tribunal. The others being asked, confessed. So they came to me. And my father appeared there also, with my son, and would draw me from the step, saying: Perform the Sacrifice; have mercy on the child. And Hilarian the procurator - he that after the death of Minucius Timinian the proconsul had received in his room the right and power of the sword - said: Spare your father's grey hairs; spare the infancy of the boy. Make sacrifice for the Emperors' prosperity. And I answered: I am a Christian.

[*The Passion of Perpetua and Felicity*, translated by W.H. Shewring](http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/text/perpetua.html)

Comment: Thank you for this addition.